# Contact Form Using Nodemailer

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, nodemailer

This may sound like a stupid question but if i were to use node mailer, express and embedded JavaScript Templates on my static website, and deployed it as normal to a host provider would it work still or would additional setup be required

Again it my be silly but i'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends, you can use a SMTP server like google's mail server and use it right out of the box or you can do something where you set up and manage your own. The second being much more involved.

https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

Comment: Hey Karim, I was thinking of using SMTP as it looks the easiest way to get it up and running quickly. If it worked locally would it work on a live server then ?

Comment: yes assuming the server can access the same outside resources your local machine can then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question Karim  its greatly appreciated :)